# How to combine values (count) from different queries into a single query

Tags: azure-data-explorer, kql, azure-monitor

Is there any way in KQL we can combine values (count) from different queries into a single query.

Currently the way I did was have two queries, get the count. Paste the values in third query and find the percentage (please refer below).

```
// First query
let football_played = database("database1").games_played
| where game_type contains "football"
| where Time > ago(1m);
football_played| count

// Second query
let registered_for_football = database("db2").registerd_players
| where EventInfo_Time > ago(1m)
| where registered_game contains "football"
registered_for_football | count

// Third query
let football_count = 13741;
let registered_count = 701588;
print cnt1 = football_count , cnt2 = registered_count 
| extend percentage = (todouble(cnt1) * 100 / todouble(cnt2))
| project percentage, cnt2, cnt1
```

Is there any way in Kql I can calculate everything in a single query and print the percentage?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you could try this:

```
let football_played = toscalar(
    database("database1").games_played
    | where Time > ago(1m)
    | where game_type contains "football"
    | count
);
let registered_for_football = toscalar(
    database("db2").registered_players
    | where EventInfo_Time > ago(1m)
    | where registered_game contains "football"
    | count
);
print football_played, registered_for_football 
| extend percentage = round(100.0 * football_played / registered_for_football, 2)
```

Comment: That does it. Thanks @Yoni L